# Changing value after parsing from API

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm parsing the following from:

````
    json.listMap.forEach((listItem: { State: string; Country: string})```

Response.data looks like this:
```{
  success: true,
  listMap: [
    {
      State : 'Northrine Westfalia',
      Country: 'Germany'
    },
    {
      {
      State : 'Bavaria',
      Country: 'Germany'
    }
    }
  ]
}
````

How can I convert the value in country currently being 'Germany' to 'Deutschland' after parsing it from the API using Java Script?

-> Let me be more open here. I don't really know that method I could use to do this. Maybe someone could point me at a documentation, of course I don't expect anyone to just hand me the code.

Comment: What you have is not JSON. It is, at best, a textual representation of a JavaScript object.

Comment: Here you have an array of items if you wanted to know how to change them all the ans is by iterating over them with any loop ex for loop and if you wanted to change each manually `listMap[0].country = "other country"` put index of item you wanted to edit hope this will help also consider making some attempts before posting and post only when you stuck anywhere

Comment: What you need is a big list of countries in various languages.  Perhaps [this package](https://github.com/hotosm/iso-countries-languages) could help.

Comment: Appreciate the help guys. Got it working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a general approach passing in the data, and from, and to arguments. It then uses [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return a new array of objects, changing the country where necessary.

Note: check your data for errors as you had some spare brackets in your example.

```js
const data = {
  success: true,
  listMap: [{
      State: 'Northrine Westfalia',
      Country: 'Germany'
    },
    {
      State: 'Bavaria',
      Country: 'Germany'
    }
  ]
}

function swap(data, prop, from, to) {
  return data.listMap.map(obj => {

    // Copy the object otherwise we'll return
    // an array of objects that point
    // to the old references
    const newObj = {...obj};
    if (newObj[prop] === from) newObj[prop] = to;
    return newObj;
  });
}

console.log(swap(data, 'Country', 'Germany', 'Deutchland'));
console.log(swap(data, 'State', 'Bavaria', 'New Bavaria'));
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that - the array was a bit longer, but wanted to limit the code, so it's easier to read. Appreciate your reply though!

Comment: @FJyaun, I've updated my answer to allow you to add a property to change. This allows you to change any value of any key, not just `Country`. Note this version returns a new object, rather than mutating the original data which the previous edit was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.map after parsing JSON into an JavaScript array:

```js
const list = response.listMap.map(entry => {
  return {
    State : entry.State,
    Country: entry.Country.replaceAll('Germany', 'Deutschland')
  }
})
```

Of course, if you need JSON structure, just convert final array into JSON string with the following:

```js
const newJSONList = JSON.stringify(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
listMap = listMap.map(listMapItem => {
if ('Germany'===listMapItem.Country) {
    listMapItem.Country = 'Deutschland';
    return listMapItem;
} else {
    return listMapItem;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming below is your response object.

```js
var responsObj={  success: true,
listMap: [
    {
      State : 'Northrine Westfalia',
      Country: 'Germany'
    },
      {
      State : 'Bavaria',
      Country: 'Germany'
    }
  ]
};
responsObj.listMap=responsObj.listMap.map(x=>{
  if(x.Country=="Germany"){
    x.Country="Deutschland";
  }
  return x;
});
console.log(responsObj.listMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help your requirement.

```
const rawJson = {
    success: true,
    listMap: [
        {
            State: 'Northrine Westfalia',
            Country: 'Germany'
        },
        {
            State: 'Bavaria',
            Country: 'Germany'
        }
    ]
};

for (itemObj of rawJson.listMap) {
    // If needed, you can add check for current value to be 'Germany'
    // if (itemObj.Country === 'Germany')
    itemObj.Country = 'Deutschland';
}

console.log(rawJson);
```

Output:

```
{
  success: true,
  listMap: [
    { State: 'Northrine Westfalia', Country: 'Deutschland' },
    { State: 'Bavaria', Country: 'Deutschland' }
  ]
}
```